# Regex C# conditional extract

Tags: c#, regex, xml

Hi I have an xml text like this

```
<w:p> abc </w:p>
<w:p> def </w:p>
<w:tr #A1b2c3> <w:p> 123 </w:p> </w:tr>
<w:tr #C1d2e3> <w:p> 456 </w:p> </w:tr>
<w:p> ghi </w:p>
```

I need to extract all paragraphs like  abc  except those inside a table row like   123  . Any help please?

Comment: use a XMLParser instead

Comment: `xpath` or `XElement` should give you access to the parent node, so you can check from there if the node is within a `w:tr` node.

Comment: I have to do it with regex, it is an obligation

Comment: @SAliaMunch - It doesn't look like XML - what's the `#A1b2c3` stuff?

Comment: @SAliaMunch - Choosing to use Regex for parsing XML might end up like using a wood saw for performing open heart surgery.

Comment: [this should do the trick](https://regex101.com/r/bLpOS1/2)

Comment: If "Use an XML Parser" is not an detail enought. [XmlDocument.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=netframework-4.8) and [XmlNode.SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8) give you `var xdoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xdoc.Load(something);
var list = xdoc.SelectNodes("//p");` 3 lines end of the story. [xpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/previous-versions/ms256086(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: `(<w:p>(.*)<\/w:p>)(?!.*<\/w:tr>)` will try to match for all `<w:p> ... </w:p>` elements except those with `</w:tr>` found on the same line. Still wont work if your `</w:tr>` elements are on separate lines

Comment: Thank you @Innat3 the regex you write works fine for me!

Comment: @SAliaMunch - What is this format? It's not XML.

Comment: @ Enigmativity the tags  contain a lot of details which are not important to the question so I replaced it with very short random text.. to put the focus on what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like valid XML so regex could be your only option:

```
^<w:p>(.*?)<\/w:p>$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QsS3tW/1

---

You may wish to figure out if there is an existing parser for that data because apparently some system must be using the data since it exists.

Comment: If the paragraph were to be contained in another element such as `<w:d>` then this would fail

Comment: @LeRoi My testing shows that it doesn't fail per your comment.

Comment: you are using the `^` symbol which indicates that the line has to start with `<w:p>` for this expression to match

Comment: @LeRoi Very observant I see. The regex works with OP's data.